# Binding dont refresh, even when explicitly calling UpdateTarget

Tags: wpf, binding

My ListView does not refresh its bindings when i call OnPropertyChanged. I have tried to force it to refresh by:

```
NestedArguments.GetBindingExpression(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty).UpdateTarget();
```

But still, no luck!

YES, it does get updated. I have set a breakpoint and checked.

What is going on?

Other bindings seem to work without a problem

Comment: Could you show us the actual binding?

Answer (score 0):

You are implement `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx` interface?

Comment: I did not have that in my .xaml file, but adding it did not change. And i have implemented it in my view model.

Answer (score 0):

is your onpropertychanged("") spelled correctly? its silly but it happens and if you arent checking for it you may miss it...

also how are you setting it? if it is a child property of a parent property you have to put the onpropertychanged notification for the child property in the parent property...

```
Public Property SelectedDoctorTaxonomy() As DoctorTaxonomy
            Get
                Return _objSelectedDoctorTaxonomy
            End Get
            Set(ByVal Value As DoctorTaxonomy)
                _objSelectedDoctorTaxonomy = Value
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedDoctorTaxonomy")
                OnPropertyChanged("DoctorID")
                OnPropertyChanged("TaxonomySpecializationID")
                OnPropertyChanged("TaxonomyTypeID")
                OnPropertyChanged("TaxonomyClassificationID")
                OnPropertyChanged("AddDate")
                OnPropertyChanged("AddUserID")
                OnPropertyChanged("ChangeDate")
                OnPropertyChanged("ChangeUserID")
            End Set
        End Property
```

HTH

Comment: For smaller apps, you can also send an empty string to PropertyChanged, and it will walk the tree and refresh everything.